# Is it possible to get function name from operator.methodcaller?

Tags: python

Is it possible to get the function name from a operator.methodcaller in Python?

```
import operator as op
mc = op.methodcaller('foo')
print magic(mc) #should print 'foo'
```

How do I do the `magic` to get the name of the method which methodcaller is calling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, but you need to dig into the C internals (not a recommended solution):

```
from ctypes import *

PyObject_HEAD = [
    ("ob_refcnt", c_size_t),
    ("ob_type", c_void_p),
]

class methodcallerobject(Structure):
    _fields_ = PyObject_HEAD + [
        ("name", c_void_p),
        ("args", c_void_p),
        ("kwds", c_void_p),
    ]

def magic(methcallobj):
    if not isinstance(methcallobj, operator.methodcaller):
        raise TypeError("not a methodcaller")

    c_methcallobj = cast(c_void_p(id(methcallobj)), POINTER(methodcallerobject)).contents

    return cast(c_methcallobj.name, py_object).value
```

Note that this only works on CPython and is not particularly beautiful. But if this is the only solution available, it's better than nothing.

Comment: Updated to remove some bugs that crashed Python - it should work out of the box now.

Comment: it 'magically' works, I think I'll have to dig into C internals to understand it, thanks a lot @nightcracker